# How to get list of keys in a dictionary with group by value with using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, group-by

Ok here a simple dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,int> dicClusters=new Dictionary<string,int>();

dicClusters.Add("A",1);
dicClusters.Add("B",1);
dicClusters.Add("C",2);
dicClusters.Add("D",3);
```

So i want to compose Lists like below from this

```
  List<List<string>> lstGroupedByKeys=dicClusters.GroupBy(pr => pr.Value)...
```

The result will be

```
first list {"A","B"}
second list {"C"}
third list {"D"}
```

i can code it with multiple foreach or using for loops however i believe it can be done with linQ and i want to learn ty

c# .NET 4.5.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GroupBy` is the right way to go, but you need another `Select` to define how each of the groups should be represented:

```
List<List<string>> lstGroupedByKeys =
    dicClusters.GroupBy(pr => pr.Value)
               .Select(g => g.Select(pr => pr.Key).ToList())
               .ToList();
```

or you can use different `GroupBy` overload:

```
List<List<string>> lstGroupedByKeys =
    dicClusters.GroupBy(pr => pr.Value, pr => pr.Key, (k, g) => g.ToList())
               .ToList();
```

It might be cleaner when using syntax-based query:

```
var lstGroupedByKeys = (from pr in dicClusters
                        group pr.Key by pr.Value into g
                        select g.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: works awesome ty. i tried with group by but i couldn't complete it :D also i prefer first solution as it makes more sense to me

Comment: can you explain this overload thingie it really looks nice. how does it works?

Comment: It's nicely described on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534493(v=vs.100).aspx